# java annotation on class FIELD is not working

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am checking spring dependency with custom annotation I have created a custom annotation in java, and I am applying this to a `FIELD`. Its working on `METHOD` but not on `FEILD`

my custom annotation is class is

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Mandatory {
}
```

My target class is:

```
public class Student {  
    @Mandatory
    int salary;

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

and my spring-configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="requiredAnnotationType" value="com.spring.core.annotation.Mandatory"/>
    </bean>


<bean id="student" class="com.spring.core.annotation.Student">
    <!-- <property name="salary" value="200000"></property> -->
</bean> 

</beans>
```

my app class is

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("annotations.xml");
        Student stud= (Student)context.getBean("student");
        System.out.println(stud);
    }
}
```

output is :`Student [salary=0]`

expected: it should throw exception property `salary` required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc, the [`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) looks at property setter methods, and not the property fields themselves.

> The motivation for the existence of this BeanPostProcessor is to allow developers to annotate the **setter properties** of their own classes with an arbitrary JDK 1.5 annotation to indicate that the container must check for the configuration of a dependency injected value.

The emphasized portion is slightly confusing, so I confirmed by looking at the [`@Required`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) annotations JavaDoc, which is the default annotation the `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` checks for.  You should notice that the `@Target` meta-annotation only references METHOD (not FIELD), and the JavaDoc mentions the following:

> Marks a method (typically a JavaBean setter method) as being 'required': that is, **the setter method** must be configured to be dependency-injected with a value.